# JS: Append variable to URL without repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Change URL parameters with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1090948/change-url-parameters-with-jquery)

Currently, I have a `<div>` tag that looks like a button and changes the URL with an onClick function which redirect to the same page just adds  `&view_all=Yes` or `&view_all=No` to the URL.

`<div onclick="javascript:window.location.href = 'page.php?action=list-volunteer-apps&view-all=No';">Hide Closed Applications</div>`

Well, I am adding a new feature to the website and I need to be able to append that `&view_all=Yes` or `&view_all=No` to the end of the URL instead of redirecting them because I'll have other variables in the URL that I can't lose.

I have figured out a way to do the append but it keeps adding the `&view_all` variables to the end of URL so it looks like this `page.php?action=list-volunteer-apps&view-all=No&view_all=Yes&view_all=No`.

This is the way I am doing the append:
`onclick="javascript:window.location.assign(window.location.href+='&view-all=No');"`

Comment: have you tried searching? the answer can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1090948/944681)

Comment: With pure JS check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9048360/how-to-extract-relative-url-from-argument-values-from-request-string/9048444#9048444) too

Comment: Yes, of course I searched. Just used the wrong search query. Thank you.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im Could you give me an example on how to use that to solve my problem? I don't know JS that well.

Comment: Using that function you can get an object or associated array of url parameters. After that you have to add/modify new value to `view_all` variable. Then build the new url. Its the opposite of that function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to replace the value in a string:

```
$(this).attr("onclick", function(i, val) {
    return val.replace(/view-all=(Yes|No)/, function() {
        return "view-all=" + ((arguments[1] || "") == "Yes" ? "No" : "Yes");
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you tell me how I would use that exactly?

Comment: @Draven For instance, like that: http://jsfiddle.net/mx7s8/.

Comment: Well, seems like a good idea but I just don't know enough JS to get it to work.